Addressing multiple USRPs with the UHD Python API
I would like to control two USRPs (B205 mini) from one Python script using the UHD Python API. Using some examples (e.g., here), I could easily do the setup with one USRP. However, when connecting now two USRPs via USB, I have no idea how to address them separately. I know the serial address for both, and realizing the task with GNURadio works as well (providing the serial addresses there). Is there any option to specify for example the keyword for uhd.usrp.MultiUSRP() accordingly? Thanks for help!

Regardless the name, "multiUSRP" supports only some of the models. B205 is not supported.
See this from past:
Why multi_usrp does not support multiple B210 radios?
